# How to share class library for more than two asp.net projects,without duplication

Tags: asp.net

How to share class library for more than two asp.net projects,without duplication.
All projects exist on the same server.

Comment: What you mean without duplication ? You have it on the dll, this dll is on the bin.

Comment: I mean only one copy of that ".dll" file should be on server. And the same should be accessible in two different projects.

Comment: Are you using VisualStudio? Are the two projects in the same solution or different solutions?

Comment: using visual studio. But projects in different solutions. Is it possible in this case or not?

Comment: What's your concern about duplication? Are the DLLs very large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the assembly into the GAC it will be available to any application that wants to reference it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx

Note:  This typically isn't how I like to build applications because if you have all of your assemblies in a lib folder then grabbing a copy of the solution from source control gets the developer a solution that will compile without having to go through additional steps like installing separate software.

From within Visual Studio, when you reference an assembly, you can pick the source location, so you can have two separate projects that reference the same DLL with no issues.